# PHProxy hanging on response

Tags: php, proxy

I've been working on a PHProxy server for some time (you can see my recent posts) and I'm at a point where I have everything working except this problem.

```
do
{
    $data = @fread($_socket, 8192);
    $_response_body .= $data;
}   
while (isset($data{0}));
unset($data);
```

My proxy server logs into a server running IIS without the user's intervention (you had to verify credentials somewhere else).  Upon logging into this site the header requests are constructed and sent but the response waits for 120 seconds on this section of code.  After that long period the proxy continues correctly as it is supposed to.  The response that I'm waiting on is just a `Object has moved here` page that gives me a new location.  I've verified headers are correct via Wireshark and LiveHttpHeaders.  Again, everything *IS* working, it just takes forever to load this particular page.

Can any PHP developers give me a hint as to what I should be checking for malfunctions?

Thanks,

EDIT:

```
[17-Jul-2010 12:33:17] BEFORE RESPONSE
[17-Jul-2010 12:35:17] AFTER RESPONSE
```

It takes 120 seconds exactly. Is something timing out?

Comment: Before anyone says so, removing the @ only warns me about faulty SSL connections, I never found any helpful errors from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code significantly increases response time, but doesn't identify the main problem of where/who/what is timing out to begin with.

```
stream_set_timeout($_socket, 1);
do
{
    $data = @fread($_socket, 8192); // silenced to avoid the "normal" warning by a faulty SSL connection
    $_response_body .= $data;
}   
while (isset($data{0}));
unset($data);
```